# How to extract netcdf data with latitude and longitude in raster as tiff?

Tags: r, hdf5, netcdf, netcdf4

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(gdalUtilities)
library(rgdal)      
library(tiff)
library(ncdf4)
library(hdf5r)
library(hdfqlr)
library(BiocManager)
library(rhdf5)
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)
library(maps)
library(fields)
library(maptools)
library(ncdf.tools)
library(ncdfgeom)
library(rgl)
library(rlas)
library(slidaRtools)
library(AnnotationDbi)
options(max.print = 99999999)
setwd("D://2R")
fname = '3B-DAY.GPM.DPRGMI.CORRAGD.20190907-S000000-E235959.250.V06A.hdf5'
ncin <- nc_open(fname)
print(ncin)
```

I have the data in hdf5 format and I open it as open_nc. The print(nc) is given below. I want to ask that how I can extract the latitude and longitude with data (**precipTotRate/mean**) from the following information.
File 3B-DAY.GPM.DPRGMI.CORRAGD.20190907-S000000-E235959.250.V06A.hdf5 (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

```
 70 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    string InputFileNames[phony_dim_96]   (Contiguous storage)  
    string InputAlgorithmVersions[phony_dim_96]   (Contiguous storage)  
    string InputGenerationDateTimes[phony_dim_96]   (Contiguous storage)  
    int G1/precipAllObs[G1/phony_dim_51,G1/phony_dim_50,G1/phony_dim_49,G1/phony_dim_48,G1/phony_dim_47]   (Chunking: [28,72,2,16,3])  (Compression: level 6)
        DimensionNames: st,hgt,ns,lnL,ltL
        _FillValue: -9999
        CodeMissingValue: -9999
    int G1/surfPrecipTotRateDiurnalAllObs[G1/phony_dim_51,G1/phony_dim_50,G1/phony_dim_49,G1/phony_dim_47,G1/phony_dim_52]   (Chunking: [28,72,2,3,21])  (Compression: level 6)
        DimensionNames: tim,st,ns,lnL,ltL
        _FillValue: -9999
        CodeMissingValue: -9999 
    float precipTotRate/mean[precipTotRate/phony_dim_4,precipTotRate/phony_dim_3,precipTotRate/phony_dim_2,precipTotRate/phony_dim_1,precipTotRate/phony_dim_0,precipTotRate/phony_dim_0]   (Chunking: [28,72,2,16,3,1])  (Compression: level 6)
        DimensionNames: rt,hgt,ns,lnH,ltH
        _FillValue: -9999.900390625
        CodeMissingValue: -9999.9
97 dimensions:
    phony_dim_96  Size:1 [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named phony_dim_96 BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
    G1/phony_dim_47  Size:3[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named G1/phony_dim_47 BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
    G1/phony_dim_48  Size:162 global attributes:
    FileHeader: DOI=10.5067/GPM/DPRGMI/CMB/3B-DAY/06; 
 DOIauthority=http://dx.doi.org/;    DOIshortName=3CMB_DAY;  
AlgorithmID=3CMB;    AlgorithmVersion=3BCMB_D_20170126;       FileName=3B-DAY.GPM.DPRGMI.CORRAGD.20190907-S000000-E235959.250.V06A.HDF5;
```

Comment: Please do not spam other posts with a link to your post.